# In ubunto 10 LXDE, can I configure LXtreminal it to open a bash --login shell

Tags: ubuntu

In ubunto with LXDE desktop there is an icon for LXTerminal when clicked on, it does not run a login shell.  I would like to set it up to run a `"bash -l"` shell.  Is there a way to do this?